# "unexpected indent" or "object has no attribute 'compile'" errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, indentation

I tried using this code from the Tensorflow [basic regression tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression):

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                       input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae'])
  return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()
```

But I get an error that says:

```
>>>   optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

If I unindent the `optimizer = ...` line, the next line gives the same error.  If I then unindent the `model.compile ...` line, I get this:

```
>>> model.compile(loss='mse',
...                 optimizer=optimizer,
...                 metrics=['mae'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

...followed by a bunch of other errors, probably resulting from that one.

The other tutorials have worked fine. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By this line of the error message

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
```

is evident that you wrote you code directly to the Python *interpreter*, and by this interpreter's prompt

```
>>>
```

is obvious that you wrote the

```
  optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)
```

as a new command on the *highest (module) level*, and NOT as a part of your *function definition*.

**How to fix it:**

You have to write the `def build_model():` command after the `>>>` prompt, and the all other command of this function definition after the `...` prompt, with the correct indentations, up to the `return model` command.

(After the `return model` command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice for returning to the `>>>` prompt; then continue writing other commands.)

Comment: Thanks!  That got me going again.  Perhaps I should have mentioned or perhaps it is obvious that this is my first foray into Python, so I'll need to work on that, too.

Comment: This misses the key point: at the REPL, the code for the function needs to *not* contain blank lines (because they will tell the REPL that you are done inputting the function code).

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, please read carefully, what I wrote, and possibly, try it yourself.

Comment: I did carefully read it. "You have to write the def build_model(): command after the >>> prompt, and the all other command of this function definition after the ... prompt, with the correct indentations, up to the return model command." This does not fully explain how to solve the problem. It is *also* necessary to *not put any blank lines* inside the function (which *are* legal in a source code file). Blank lines are unrelated to "correct indentations". I also understand extremely well how this works and don't need to try something this simple - I have been using Python since 2005.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I have been using Python since 2000 (version 1.6) and in spite of it I always try what I then write as an answer. So I again recommend you trying it. (You may understand **extremely** well how this works, and in spite of it be wrong. It is not an argument.)

Comment: I did try it. It did not work, exactly as I expected it not to work, because I inserted a blank line, which causes the problem but which your instructions do not warn against. So, in fact, did OP: the code is correctly indented, as demonstrated by copying and pasting it to a source code file and `import`ing it, which does not cause a `SyntaxError`, whereas copying and pasting it to the REPL does. Again: a blank line has nothing to do with indentation, therefore, someone who adds a blank line to the function definition may still type it "with the correct indentations".

Comment: Yes, you said to press `Enter` twice after `return model` (which, incidentally, is not a "command"). But you did *not* say *not* to do it *before* that point. Which is the issue with the answer. (Aside from the fact that the question is a common duplicate, and should not have been answered... but the canonical for this is not well known.)